# Find difference between two 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, difference

How do I find the difference between two 2D array in python ?

First array and second array

```
arr1 = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5]]
arr2 = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]
```

The result I want

```
result = [[1,1],[1,5]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Numpy get difference between 2 two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66674537/python-numpy-get-difference-between-2-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first convert all element to `tuple` then use `set` and `difference` like below:

```
>>> set(map(tuple,arr1)).difference(map(tuple,arr2))
{(1, 1), (1, 5)}

>>> list(map(list , set(map(tuple,arr1)).difference(map(tuple,arr2))))
[[1,1],[1,5]]
```